# Polymer 1.0 bind function in dom bind

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm trying to bind the function from dom-bind to nested element as below.
Somehow the on-click binding is not working.
I get the message in console pane: [dom-bind::_createEventHandler]: listener method `{{handleClick}}` not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>auto-binding test</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>

</head>
<body unresolved>
<dom-module id="number-element" >
    <template>
        I'm number <span>{{number}}</span>. Click me!
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{odd}}">
            (By the way, I'm odd.)
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'number-element',
            properties: {
                number: {
                    value: 0,
                    reflectOnAttributes: true,
                    observer: "numberChanged",
                    type: Number,
                    notify: true
                },
                odd: {
                    value: false,
                    type: Boolean,
                    notify: true

                }
            },
            numberChanged: function() {
                this.odd = this.number % 2 == 1 ? true : false;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<template id="page-template" is="dom-bind">
    <h1>&lt;template is="auto-binding"&gt; Demo</h1>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{lastClicked}}">
        <p>You last clicked on <span>{{lastClicked}}</span>.</p>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{numbers}}" as="item">
        <p>
            <number-element number="[[item]]" on-click="{{handleClick}}"></number-element>
        </p>
    </template>
</template>
<script>
    var template = document.querySelector('#page-template');
    template.isNumberOdd = {};
    template.numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    template.handleClick = function(e) {
        template.lastClicked = e.target.number;
    };    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use braces around the event name. Change it as below and it should work

```
<number-element number="[[item]]" on-click="handleClick"></number-element>
```